# 503 on local requests

Tags: 2010, error

For some reason our SharePoint server rejects local requests with `503 Service Unavailable`. Everything works fine when a user browses a site (e.g. http://spserver/) from another machine in the network. However, if the same user logs in to the server (RDP) and attempts to browse the same site from within the server they either:

1. Continuously get the login prompt (if using the FQDN e.g. http://spserver/)
2. Get a `503 Service Unavailable` error (if using http://localhost/)

**NOTE:** The password is fine and the application pools are running fine (since users can connect remotely)

Any ideas please?

Comment: Are you sure http://localhost is referencing the exact same web site in IIS as http://spserver? Did you extend a web application from http://localhost to http://spserver or set one of those host headers up as an alternate access mapping (AAM) of another? If not, I would be inclined to believe you are hitting two separate web sites in IIS via these two host headers. I agree with Dave Wise's answer below for continuously getting the login prompt if using the FQDN on the local server (assuming it gives you a 401 after three failed attempts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the common "Loopback Issue" that happens when accessing a site from the server that is hosting it.  Microsoft has [a solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861) for this and I've had very good luck using option #2 to fix the issue.